# Can I set my dns zone at my hosting provider to a domain purchased somewhere else?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, dns

I am going to choose as my hosting provider [NetCup.eu](https://www.netcup.eu/) which is located in Germany and has interesting and affordable VPS and root server solutions. 
They also sell domains, however they are not as cheap as those at `NameCheap`, so, if I can, I would like to purchase a domain at `NameCheap`. 
Since `NetCup` would host my server, I am going to use their name servers. 
I asked their customer support if I will be able to edit my dns zone and add my domain from `NameCheap` and instructions on how to do that, however they were unable to understand my question, or be of any help. 
So here I am, to understand if my query does make any sense.

Comment: It is usually just a matter of getting values for your NS records from your web host (NetCup) and setting the NS record values at the registrar (NameCheap).      If you phrase it in terms on "nameserver records" (NS records), their customer support will probably be able to give you more detailed information.

Comment: Yes it is possible, but as a webhost I will share something I tell my customers "Having everything in one place can help avoid confusion, tears and heartache" - Trust me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Your VPS should provide you with at least one IP address.  You can then take that to NameCheap (or whoever you register the domain with) and create an A record to point the domain to that IP address.  It is fairly common.

Name Servers are also an option, but I believe you'll really only be given an IP address.

https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/43/11/how-do-i-set-up-a-host-for-dynamic-dns

The link above should help you.